# Menu hiding behind search box on one page

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

Wordpress site - https://www.planninggeek.co.uk/

The home page has a search box and the dropdown menu above goes on top of it.

However if I go to the search page - https://www.planninggeek.co.uk/?s=

The the search box is on top of the menu dropdown.

I have played around with z-index but drawn a blank.

Anyone have an idea as to why this is happening.  The code for the box is the same.

Comment: Try setting the z-index here: `#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_2 #mega-menu-max_mega_menu_2 li#mega-menu-item-5922 .mega-search-wrap` to a lesser value. Something like 10.

Comment: Your should not link to external page but include all code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

mega-search-wrap mega-static has a z-index